# Custom validation attribute that allows specific integer in C#

Tags: c#, .net-5

How to create a custom validation attribute that allows only specified integers. adding a custom error message.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and inherit from `ValidationAttribute` class.

Follow the example code below

```
public class IntegersAllowedAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        private readonly int[] _values;

        public IntegersAllowedAttribute(params int[] values)
        {
            _values = values;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            int valuesToValidate = (int)value;

            if (!_values.Contains(valuesToValidate))
            {
                string errorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName);
                return new ValidationResult(errorMessage);
            }
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
    }
```

Then place attribute on the property

```
 public class Example
    {
        [IntValuesAllowed(1, 2, 3, ErrorMessage = "error message goes here")]
        public int Values { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Interesting behavior to create question and immediately give an answer to that ))